# Passing Between Components Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I currently have 3 components stacked like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-body></app-body>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

However I want to switch it so that the footer and body positioning is different like below:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<app-body></app-body>
```

Once I change the placement of  and  the footer is no longer loading anything from the dataservice.
Constructor inside footer.component.ts:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    //subscribing the the dataService so that we can display its contents
    this.dataService.currentNoms.subscribe(noms => {this.nominations.push(noms);});
  }
```

Constructor inside body.component.ts:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) { 
    //adding the nominations to my dataService to use between components
    this.dataService.addNominations(this.nominations);
  }
```

data.Service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private finalNoms = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentNoms = this.finalNoms.asObservable();

  constructor() { 
    this.addNominations(this.nominations);
  }

  addNominations(nom: Object){
    this.finalNoms.next(nom);
  }

}
```

I tried swapping the contents of the constructor but that doesnt seem to be helping. Anyone know what im doing wrong? New to Angular, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It stands to reason that your BodyComponent is being loaded after your Footer component, and so this line of code has not been executed by the time your Footer component requests the data:

```
this.dataService.addNominations(this.nominations);
```

I would suggest moving the above line of code into the costructor of the Data Service, so that the data is always available, once the service becomes available.

Alternatively, you could leverage [rxjs Subjects](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) in your data service to asynchoronously set and retrieve the data:

```js
// In data.service.ts
nominations = new BehaviorSubject([...]);
nominations$ = this.nominations.asObservable();

addNomination(nom) {
    const noms = this.nominations.value;
    noms.push(nom);
    this.nominations.next(noms);
}
```

```js
// In body.component.ts
nominations: any[]; // Or the interface/type you're using

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations$.subscribe(noms => this.nominations = noms);
}

addNomination(nom: any) {
   this.dataService.addNomination(nom);
}
```

```js
// In footer.component.ts
nominations: any[];

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.nominations$.subscribe(noms => this.nomations = noms);
}
```

Comment: if I add that line to my data.service.ts I will get an error that "Property 'dataService' does not exist on type 'DataService'." not entirely sure this is the right idea as we are now calling the dataService inside the dataService

Comment: for more info, the body is allowing the user to search, and as the user search and adds an item to the list in the dataService, the item needs to be displayed in the footer

Comment: When adding it to the Data Service, you wouldn't need to reference the data service, it would just be: this.addNominations(this.nominations);

Comment: added my dataservice above. Im not sure that will work, or im not seeing how it will.

Comment: The idea is that you move all of the nominations logic into the service, so that the body component just asks for the data and manipulates it if necessary. To do that you'll need to move the nomications to the dat aserver and provide getters, setters and other modifying methods to interact with the array:

`nomination: any[] = [...]`
`get nominations() { return this.nominations; }`
`set nominations(noms: any[]) { this.nomations = noms; }`
`addNomination(nom: any) { this.nominations.push(nom) }`

Comment: You'll need to use the observable approach anyways if you want your list to be reflected in the Footer component

Comment: @DerekS I've updated the post to include a solution that uses observables, I highly recommend you read up on rxjs and observables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can achieve if you eclosed yours component in a div flex

```
<div [style]="display:flex;flex-direction: column"
     *ngIf="{order:orderService.currentNoms|async} as order" >
  <app-header [style.order]="order.order?order.order[0]:null"></app-header>
  <app-body [style.order]="order.order?order.order[1]:null"></app-body>
  <app-footer [style.order]="order.order?order.order[2]:null"></app-footer>
</div>
```

You main.cmponent

```
  constructor(public orderService:OrderService){}
```

Your service

```
export class OrderService {

  private finalNoms = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentNoms = this.finalNoms.asObservable();

  setOrder(order:any[])
  {
    this.finalNoms.next(order)
  }
```

Inside any component **in ngOnInit**

```
 this.orderService.setOrder([1,3,2]) //change the order
```

A [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzwizv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)